# confused about user register and change password on Tomcat server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets

As for form-based website authentication, Tomcat will do authentication with  right configuration(login part). I'm confused about user regiser and password resetting. When user submits register usename and password(or change password), salted hash password needs to be added or updated in database. Is it done by tomcat? If not, how to do this in servlet?